# Why is the background color disappearing?

Tags: css, background, header

Take a look at the #header container at http://granthoneymoon.com/temp.html

At the browser widths of 360 to 499 the background color of the #header disappears and I have no idea why. It's basically the same css as the other widths! It works fine in dreamweaver, but when actually viewed in a browser (IE or Firefox) the problem surfaces. Any clues as to what's going on???

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 954px)  {
    #header {
    background-color: #18436C;
    min-height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) and (min-width: 360) {
#header {
    background-color: #18436C;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 359px) {
#header {
    background-color: #18436C;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 360px;
    min-height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
}
```

Comment: Why to define the same color three times? If screen exceeds 954 pixels than background color should be different? If not, define it only once  outside all the media query blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the unit for `min-width`:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) and (min-width: 360) {
```

should be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) and (min-width: 360px) {
```

---

Btw. why don't you separate the common values and avoid so much repetition?

```
#header {
    background-color: #18436C;
    min-height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 954px)  {

}
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) and (min-width: 360px) {
#header {
    width: 100%;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 359px) {
#header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 360px;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The reason for the repetition was simple copying and pasting. Quick way to make sure the formatting works at the different levels. 

I missed the "px" that was the problem. Great catch!!